# textarea:valid + label doesn't work correctly when on a server

Tags: html, css, server, web

I am trying to create some label text on a contact form that when the contact form is the :focus or it is :valid, the text moves above the input box and stays there.

Everything works fine on my local machine (Using brackets live preview), however, whenever I put the code onto my website for some reason the textarea label doesn't move anymore?

Has anybody got any idea why this is?

Here is the full code:

```
<div class="section">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>Contact Me</h2>
                <form action="contactme.php" method="post" class="contact-form">
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <input type="text" name="name" required="">
                        <label for="">Full Name</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-field">
                        <input type="text" name="cname" required="">
                        <label for="">Company Name</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-field">
                        <input type="text" name="website" required="">
                        <label for="">Current Website (N/A if None)</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-field">
                        <input type="email" name="mail" required="">
                        <label for="">E-Mail</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-field">
                        <textarea name="message" rows="5" required=""></textarea>
                        <label for="">Message</label>
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Message" class="btn">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

-

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 142, 204, 5) 50%, rgba(253, 165, 15, 5) 50%);
}

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 600px;
    padding: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    animation: fadeIn 2s 0s linear;
}

.wrapper h2 {
    color: #666;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.input-field {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.input-field input,
.input-field textarea {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #666;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #666;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    resize: none;
}

.input-field label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #666;
    font-weight: 700;
    transition: .5s;
}

.input-field input:focus + label,
.input-field textarea:focus + label,
.input-field input:valid + label,
.input-field textarea:valid + label {
    top: -25px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    background: #FF006A;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.btn {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff9966, #ff5e62);
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: right;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media(max-width: 580px) {

    .wrapper {
        width: 250px;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .wrapper h2 {
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .input-field input,
    .input-field textarea {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .input-field label {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .btn {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

}
```

Comment: it seems to work on jsfiddle... is it the same for you? https://jsfiddle.net/7ydhvt82/

Comment: Works fine for me on jsfiddle but when I take it onto my host this is what happens:
https://gyazo.com/61224ebc52a4cfaca8b55831ee0fc616

Comment: I've also just discovered that when I first reload the page, it works correctly but then it's like to updates and doesn't work again:
https://gyazo.com/26c11c0dd5bd5fcf3a5453da5940139d

Comment: you have the same problem on jsfiddle if you add an invalid email address (without @) and then move to another field. You should change the rules in your css.

Comment: probably this is the best way to achieve what you want: http://jsbin.com/pagiti/11/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Thanks. But why does it work fine on my local computer but on a server it breaks?

Comment: In my css I change the code to this and added a placehodler to each field but it still doesn't work:

[code].input-field input:focus + label,
.input-field textarea:focus + label,
.input-field input:not(:placeholder-shown) + label,
.input-field textarea::not(:placeholder-shown) + label {
    top: -25px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    background: #FF006A;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 4px;
}[/code]